# Remote GVIM with Xming hangs when lost and restored focus

Tags: windows-7, remote, gvim, freebsd, xming

I have a following setup: a Windows 7 laptop with Xming installed and FreeBSD with GVIM in VirtualBox. I set up everything (set DISPLAY env variable, opened ports, allowed Xming to accept connections from outside of localhost, etc) so that when I execute a program in a shell on FreeBSD it's opening as another window on my desktop. Basically, everything works.

Except that not quite. I use this setup mainly for GVIM, and it works very well if it's the only opened remote program at a time. It's not a problem most of the time, but sometimes I want to open another X program alongside vim (mainly urxvt or gqview). In that case, changing focus from GVIM to another remote aplication and back causes GVIM to freeze for several seconds and then it resumes working as before. Keypresses are not lost and the "X" button works (kills GVIM). Other remote apps do not display this behaviour.

Basically, every time I do alt+tab to a different (but **only** remote!) window, gvim stops responding for a while (about 15-20 seconds on average).

I have another, physical box with FreeBSD and GVIM on it and it displays exactly the same behaviour. I have compiled GVIM from ports with following options, as given by `:version`:

```
Duża wersja z GTK2 GUI.  Opcje włączone (+) lub nie (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal
+cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs +dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path
+float +folding -footer +fork() +gettext -hangul_input +iconv +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu
+mksession +modify_fname +mouse +mouseshape +mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm +mouse_netterm +mouse_sysmouse +mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme
+netbeans_intg -osfiletype +path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python -python3 +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby +scrollbind +signs
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar
 +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup +X11 -xfontset +xim +xsmp_interact
+xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
       vimrc systemu: "$VIM/vimrc"
   vimrc użytkownika: "$HOME/.vimrc"
    exrc użytkownika: "$HOME/.exrc"
     gvimrc systemu: "$VIM/gvimrc"
  gvimrc użytkownika: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
 systemowy plik menu: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
   odwet dla $VIM-a: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Kompilacja: cc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/local/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/gtk-2.0/include -I/usr/local/inc
lude/atk-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/cairo -I/usr/local/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/local/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/local/include -I/us
r/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include/libpng -I/usr/local/include  -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing
-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Konsolidacja: cc -L/usr/local/lib -lXt -L. -L/usr/lib  -rpath=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib -pthread -rdynamic  -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,--as-needed -o vim     -pthread -L/usr/lo
cal/lib -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lXext -lXrender -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXcursor -lXcomposite -lXdamage -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.
0 -lgio-2.0 -lXfixes -lcairo -lX11 -lpango-1.0 -lm -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0  -lSM -lICE -lXpm  -lXt  -lXdmcp -lSM -l
ICE  -lm -lelf  -pthread -ltermlib -liconv -lintl          -L/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -lutil -lm -Wl,--export-dynamic      -Wl,-R -Wl,/usr/local/lib
-L/usr/local/lib -lruby18 -lcrypt -lm -L/usr/lib  -rpath=/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib -pthread
```

Please tell me one of two things: what to do to make this behaviour go away or where else I could ask this question to have highest probability of getting response?

Thanks!

Comment: Just guessing, did you try to use another Toolkit like athena or motif? They are less bloated so might be faster. Since you are on ugly windows, it doesn't matter that they are not as pretty as the GTK UI :)

Comment: @arved sounds good! I'll try recompiling with other gui.